# how to sequence number based n + 1 in ruby

Tags: ruby, numbers

How to sequence number based n + 1 in ruby ?

i have case like this :

```
digit = 10
```

how to get result like this in format string :

```
result = "12345678910"
```

if i try this code :

```
result = (1..digit).to_a.join.to_s
```

yes this code is work, but when i have digit 1000000000 or more, my memory is leak...

thanks before

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
nbr = 10   
result = (1..nbr).to_a.join.to_s
```

If you have big numbers, you can use a [Generator](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ruby/ruby-67.3/ruby/lib/generator.rb)

```
require 'generator'

nbr = 10000

result = ""

my_generator = Generator.new((1..nbr))

while my_generator.next?
    result+=my_generator.next
end
```

Comment: Don't you mean `result = (1..digit).to_a.join.to_s`

Comment: if i have digit = 1000000000, my memory is down, how to make code the fast without convert digit to array

Comment: @AlexPeachey's does what you want (without creating an array).

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres when i try require 'generator' in irb, the generator undifined ?

Comment: @tardjo I did not understand the purpose of your comment.

Comment: the class Generator not working

Comment: yes, the generator not exists in ruby console

Comment: did you put require 'generator' ?

Comment: yes, i put the require generator @VictorCastilloTorres

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this:

```
digit = 10
result = (1..digit).reduce('') { |r,d| r += d.to_s }
```

Comment: Or use Victor's, it's nicer.